# Getting unauthorised error from mongoid with username and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm getting "unauthorized" error from mongoid, when access auth enabled mongo server. Exception is not raised when I disable auth option in mongo.

Can anybody point me out why I'm getting this error?

```
irb(main):010:0> Test.count
  MOPED: 10.0.0.4:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 1.7334ms
  MOPED: 10.0.0.4:27017 COMMAND      database=staging command={:count=>"tests", :query=>{}} runtime: 1.0563ms
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=91
  @request_id=9
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="staging.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:count=>"tests", :query=>{}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error "unauthorized"
```

Permission of the user looks like this.

```
> use staging
switched to db staging
> show users
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
    "pwd" : "xxx",
    "roles" : [
        "readWrite",
        "dbAdmin"
    ],
    "user" : "username"
}
```

My mondoid.yml looks like this.

```
staging:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: staging
      username: username
      password: "password"
      hosts:
        - 10.0.0.4:27017
```

There is no problem when I access mongo from my console using this user.

Environment

```
rails 4.0.2
mongoid 4.0.0.alpha1
```

Comment: We have the problem too, and it looks like we're not alone : https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in moped gem, which mongoid relys on.
https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/243